# Click on multiple instances

Tags: jquery

I am using slick slider for a series of slides, in EACH slide (total of 10) I have placed a previous / next navigation that is single sourced.

Issue:
when I click on the first set, it does work, however when the next slide comes in the SAME previous/next buttons don't trigger. I've tried doing
`.each()` but it no luck.

```
jQuery("#arrownext").click(function(each){
    jQuery(".slick-next").click();
});

jQuery("#arrowprev").click(function(each){
    jQuery(".slick-prev").click();
});
```

So each slider will have an instance of `#arrownext` and arrowprev and trying to make each instance clickable.

Comment: IDs need to be unique in a document so you can't have `#arrownext` and `#arrowprev` in each slider. But perhaps this was just a misunderstanding and you would like to trigger each previous/next slider button using one "master" previous/next button?

Comment: please create a working snippet

Comment: @SaschaM78 exactly, for each previous/next based on ONE master.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the id's to class and it works great. Cannot have multiple instances of the same ID apparently, at least for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You might be reloading the page or just recreating the #arrownext and #arrowprev buttons because of that jquery click events you attached to initial buttons are no longer exists. In this case, just try the following.

```
$( "body #arrownext" ).on( "click", function(each) {
  jQuery(".slick-next").click();
}); 

$( "body #arrowprev" ).on( "click", function(each) {
  jQuery(".slick-prev").click();
});
```

Comment: yeah I tried, that, but never work. It turned out to be IDs meaning using classes work.